# Drawing on multiple surfaces by using only EGLSurface?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

Is it possible to draw from the same application on multiple surfaces, one by one, by using only the handler returned by eglCreateWindowSurface ?

What i want to achieve is to create two or more surfaces and pass them to a client who will draw on them, and then, when done, basically, i will only need to perform swapBuffers.
A simple surface handler ( EGLSurface ) will be enough for the client to draw shapes etc ?

I cannot find any examples; each examples just draws in the current context.

Comment: An EGLSurface is not enough for the client to draw. GLES drawing is *always* done in the current context. You'll have to eglMakeCurrent to associate the context with the surface, before drawing. (And if you are on Android, you'll have to be running on the GL thread associated with that context. I.e. inside your draw method, unless you created the GL thread yourself, perhaps similar to Grafika on github.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this, but it should be possible. On the EGL level, the association between context and surface is established when you make a context current with the [`eglMakeCurrent()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml) call:

```
EGLBoolean eglMakeCurrent( EGLDisplay display,
                           EGLSurface draw,
                           EGLSurface read,
                           EGLContext context);
```

The `EGLSurface` you pass to this call (typically the same for `read` and `draw`) can come from the return value of `eglCreateWindowSurface()`.

So if you're currently drawing to `surface1`, and you want to start rendering to `surface2`, you can use:

```
eglMakeCurrent(eglGetCurrentDisplay(), surface2, surface2,
               eglGetCurrentContext());
```

Note that each surface can only be current for one context at a time. From the EGL 1.4 spec:

> at most one context may be bound to a particular surface at a given time

Comment: So i cannot pass to the client two EGLSurfaces, without making them active, first of off, because i think the last call to eglMakeCurrent will override the first one
The idea is that i just want to create the surfaces, pass them further to the the painter, and then just swapBuffers, but i can deduce that this is not possible because in order for the painter to draw, the surface(s) must must be passed through eglMakeCurrent.
Would the only possibility be to pass: EGLContext, EGLSurface and EGLDisplay in order to enable the painter the ability to handle them with eglMakeCurrent and swapBuffers?

Answer (score 4):

I would go about this by creating an openGL framebuffer backed by a texture.  I'd do my complicated drawing to that once.  Then I'd draw a quad on each EGLSurface using the texture id.

something like:

```
eglMakeCurrent();

// generate na FB
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mContextParams->mTexture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                           GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture, 0);
```

Then draw fancy stuff to framebuffer:

```
eglMakeCurrent();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

// do draw here

// unbind
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then draw to screen:

```
for (everyEGLContext)
{
   eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
   drawQuad(texture);
   eqlSwapBuffers(display, surface);
}
```